# React does not show all value of an array returned from axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, setstate, use-effect

This is my backend `NodeJS` code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const cors = require('cors');

app.get('/getEmployees', cors(), (req, res) => {
    res.send([
        '00001 | Alice',
        '00002 | Bob',
        '00003 | Charlie',
        '00004 | Dave',
        '00005 | Eve',
        '00006 | Frank',
    ]);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is my frontend React code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import classes from './App.module.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

    const [employeesList, setEmployeesList] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/getEmployees').then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data); // Checking value
            let list = [];
            response.data.map((employee) => {
                list.push(<option>{employee}</option>)
                return setEmployeesList(list)
            })
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={classes.App}>
            Please select employee:
            <select>
                {employeesList}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

When I run them, I can see a drop down list on the browser but there is only 1 value, which is the first employee, Alice.

[image]

As you see, I do `console.log` in the `axios` function and it prints multiple employees. I expect to see all employees in the drop down list. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You are doing a bunch of things incorrectly. I would recommend to `console.log(employeesList)` before `return` of App function. That should clear things for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `useEffect` as below :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/getEmployees').then((response) => {
      response.data.map((employee, index) => {
        list.push(<option key={index.toString()}>{employee}</option>)
      })
      setEmployeesList(list);
    });
  }, []);
```

**[Codesandbox Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-pascal-djihq)**

Comment: This works!. Just move `setEmployeeList(list)` to be outside the map function. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is inside the map function callback which in this case returns a 2D array of elements, I recommend to set the raw data in state then use map inside the jsx to render the items :

```
function App() {

    const [employeesList, setEmployeesList] = useState([]);//init the state as an empty array

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/getEmployees').then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data); // Checking value
                 setEmployeesList(response.data)
            
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={classes.App}>
            Please select employee:
            <select>
                {employeesList.map((emp,index)=>{
                  
                   return <option key={index} value={emp}>{emp}</option>

                 }}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};
```